# (iphone) when or how to get the uiview height size after layoutSubviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, height

in my viewcontroller I make my instance of my view class ( in the viewdidload method)
in that view class I implement the layoutsubviews method and add all kinds of subviews there

now since that view class is part of a uiscrollview i want to make the scrollview contentsize as large as the view class

how do i get the height of my viewclass?

```
tableInfo = [[TableInfoView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 0)];
[scrollView addSubview:tableInfo];
NSLog(@"%f", tableInfo.height);
```

seems it doesn't automatically adjusts the frame height size or is it to soon to get the height ? .. i'm not quite sure.. because it displays correctly ..

how can i immediately call the layoutsubviews when i init the view class ?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be immediate, but you can call the view's `setNeedsLayout` method pretty much whenever you'd like in your controller's code. This will schedule the view for layout. (You really shouldn't ever be calling `layoutSubviews` directly.)